# Why does the GUI Freezes while waiting for data in Kivy?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, kivy, kivy-language

I was trying to implement a loading animation while waiting for data from the server, but the loading animation does not run properly until the data was received from the server. I tried using Thread as to not interrupt the GUI but still does not work as expected

Here is a working program that I had been working on.

`main.py`

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
import multiprocessing
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from threading import Thread
from kivy.config import Config
from client import *
from time import sleep

Builder.load_file("project1.kv")
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0')  # 0 being off 1 being on as in true/false
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '700')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '1000')
Config.write()


class AddressScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AddressScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        AddressScreen.ip = 0
        self.sock = None
        self.text = 0
        self.recv = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.send = multiprocessing.Queue()

    def connection(self):
        address = self.manager.get_screen("address")
        AddressScreen.ip = address.ids.ip.text
        try:
            self.sock = MySocket(AddressScreen.ip)
            self.manager.current = "loading"
            self.manager.transition.direction = "left"
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            sleep(0.1)
            self.manager.current = "connect"
            self.manager.transition.direction = "left"

    def get_data_thread(self):
        g_data = Thread(target=self.get_data)
        g_data.start()
        data = self.recv.get()
        return data

    def send_text(self):
        self.send_data("+OK")

    def get_data(self):
        while True:
            self.recv.put(self.sock.get_data())


    def send_data(self, msg=None):
        self.sock.send_data(msg.encode())


class LoadingWindow(Screen):  # incomplete
    # disable the button until the chair had been set up (+OK signal from raspberry pi)
    # insert in between every test window (done)
    # (Extra) add loading bar

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(LoadingWindow, self).__init__(**kw)

        self.response = None
        self.tmp = 0

    def on_enter(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.loading)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.enable_load_button)

    def loading(self, *kwargs):
        loading_grid = self.ids.loading
        anim = Animation(height=120, width=120, spacing=[10, 10], duration=0.5)
        anim += Animation(height=90, width=90, spacing=[10, 10], duration=0.5)
        anim += Animation(angle=loading_grid.angle + 45, duration=0.5)
        anim.bind(on_complete=self.loading)
        anim.start(loading_grid)

    def disable_load_button(self):
        load_screen = self.manager.get_screen("loading")
        load_screen.ids.load_button.disabled = True
        self.manager.current = "address"
        self.manager.transition.direction = "left"

    def home(self):
        self.manager.current = "address"
        self.manager.transition.direction = "left"

    def enable_load_button(self, *kwargs):

        load_screen = self.manager.get_screen("loading")
        control = self.manager.get_screen('address')

        def check_response(dt):
            self.response = control.get_data_thread()
            if self.response.decode('utf-8') == "OK":
                print(self.response.decode('utf-8'))
                load_screen.ids.load_button.disabled = False
                control.sock.close()
            else:
                print("Wrong Data")
                print(self.response.decode('utf-8'))
                # Schedule the check_response function again after a delay
                Clock.schedule_once(check_response, 1.0)  # Adjust the delay as needed

        Clock.schedule_once(check_response, 0.0)  # Adjust the delay as needed
        # Start checking for the response


class Overlay(BoxLayout):
    pass


class NavDrawer(BoxLayout):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class ConnectionWindow(Screen):  # establish connection Here if not then have a button to retry
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ConnectionWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def reconnect(self):
        control = self.manager.get_screen('title')
        try:
            control.connection()
        except WindowsError:
            print("No Connection")

    def top(self):
        self.manager.current = "address"
        self.manager.transition.direction = "up"

    pass


class MyMainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Orange"  # Choose a darker color palette, like "Gray"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "800"
        self.theme_cls.secondary_palette = "Grey"
        self.sm = WindowManager()
        return self.sm


# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyMainApp().run()
```

`client.py`

```
import socket


class MySocket:

    #def __init__(self, host="133.54.230.189", port=8000):
    def __init__(self, host, port=8000):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.settimeout(1)
        self.sock.connect((host, port))
        self.sock.settimeout(60)

        print("Connected")

    def close(self):
        self.sock.close()
    def get_data(self):
        recv_msg = self.sock.recv(1024)
        return recv_msg

    def send_data(self, send_msg):
        self.sock.send(send_msg)
```

`server.py`

```
import socket
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from time import sleep
response = Queue()
comm = Queue()


def server(response, comm):
    serversocket = socket.socket()

    SERVER_ADDRESS = ("localhost", 8000)
    serversocket.bind(SERVER_ADDRESS)

    serversocket.listen(5)
    print(f"Address is : {SERVER_ADDRESS}")
    while True:
        try:
            clientsocket, addr = serversocket.accept()
            print("got a connection from %s" % str(addr))
            while True:
                recv_msg = clientsocket.recv(1024)
                print(recv_msg.decode('utf-8'))
                comm.put(recv_msg.decode('utf-8'))
                send_msg = response.get()
                print(send_msg)
                clientsocket.send(str(send_msg).encode())
                if not recv_msg:
                    print("Connection closed  due to  lack of data")
                    clientsocket.close()
        except ConnectionResetError:
            print("Connection Reset, Waiting for new connection")
            clientsocket.close()
        finally:
            print("Connection Reset, Waiting for new connection")
            clientsocket.close()


def worker_thread(response, comm):
    while True:


        control = comm.get()
        sleep(0.1)
        if control == "+OK":
            sleep(3)
            response.put("OK")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Process(target=server, args=(response, comm,))
    worker = Process(target=worker_thread, args=(response, comm,))

    worker.start()
    s.start()

    pass
```

`project1.kv`

```
<WindowManager>:
    AddressScreen:
    LoadingWindow:
    ConnectionWindow:




<MDTopAppBar>:
    title: "Locomotion Age Measurement"
    title_size : "20sp"
    title_font_name :"meiryo.ttc"
    size_hint: (1, 0.1)
    elevation: 10
    pos_hint : {"center_x" : 0.5 , "center_y" : 0.975}
<MDNavigationDrawer>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'

<LoadingWindow>:
    name : "loading"
    MDFloatLayout:
        md_bg_color : 0,0,0,0
        MDGridLayout:
            id :loading
            angle : 0
            rows:2
            cols:2
            size_hint: None,None
            height:100
            width:100
            pos_hint:{"center_x":.5,"center_y":.6}
            spacing:5
            canvas.before:
                PushMatrix
                Rotate:
                    angle : self.angle
                    axis:0,0,1
                    origin: self.center
            canvas.after:
                PopMatrix
            MDFloatLayout:
                md_bg_color:rgba(242,80,34,255)
            MDFloatLayout:
                md_bg_color:rgba(242,80,34,255)
            MDFloatLayout:
                md_bg_color:rgba(242,80,34,255)
            MDFloatLayout:
                md_bg_color:rgba(242,80,34,255)




    MDLabel :
        id:loading_label
        text : "Please Wait 3 Seconds"
        pos_hint : {"center_x" : 0.5 , "center_y" : 0.4}
        halign :"center"
        size_hint_x :1
        font_size : "25sp"



    MDRectangleFlatIconButton :

        id : load_button
        icon:"arrow-right"
        text : "Proceed"
        pos_hint : {"center_x" : 0.5 , "center_y" : 0.25}
        disabled : True
        on_release :
            root.disable_load_button()


    MDTopAppBar:
        left_action_items: [['home', lambda x: root.home()]]
<AddressScreen>

    name : "address"
    FloatLayout:
        GridLayout:
            halign:"center"
            row_force_default :"True"
            row_default_height :"80"

            pos_hint:{"center_x" : 0.5 , "center_y" : 0.70}


            size_hint_y:0.2
            size_hint_x:0.8
            column:1
            rows:2


            MDTextField :
                id : ip
                text:"localhost"
                hint_text:"IP Address"
                required:True

                size_hint_x:1
                multiline : False
                helper_text :"e.g : 127.0.0.1"
                icon_left: 'key-variant'
                normal_color: app.theme_cls.accent_color
                color_active: 211/255, 211/255, 211/255, 1


        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            pos_hint : {"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.3}
            text : "Start"
            halign:"center"
            size_hint_x: 0.7
            on_release :
                root.connection()
                root.send_text()

    Overlay:
        id: dim_overlay
        opacity: 1 if root.ids.nav_drawer.state == "open" else 0
        on_touch_down: root.ids.nav_drawer.set_state("closed")

    MDTopAppBar:
        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
        anchor_title: "center"

    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'

<ConnectionWindow>

    name : "connect"
    MDLabel :
        id:connect_label
        text : "Connection Failed Try Again"
        pos_hint : {"center_x" : 0.5 , "center_y" : 0.5}
        halign : "center"
        size_hint_x : 0.8
        font_size : self.width/25
    MDRectangleFlatButton :
        id : connect_return
        text : "Return"
        pos_hint : {"center_x" : 0.25 , "center_y" : 0.5}
        disabled : False
        on_release :
            root.top()
```

I think that by using Queue() it is still blocking my GUI from running properly but I don't have any idea on how to run the thread and return the data without using Queue().

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but in your `get_data_thread()` method you call `self.recv.get()` which blocks until there is something to get.

Comment: I kinda figured out this is the issue after i tweaked around for a little bit. Is there any workaround for me to use so that i can obtain data from get_data_thread() without using self.recv.get()?

Comment: I cannot run your code (possibly kivymd version issues). But, in general, you should run anything that might take enough time to interfere with the GUI in another thread. You can actually run everything on another thread, and just use `Clock.schedule_once()` or `@mainthread` to put only GUI code on the main thread.